# Cannot track clicks with Universal Links integration on app

Tags: firebase-analytics, mobile-development, ios-universal-links

I've implemented [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/) on a news app so that links to the website will open the app instead (if it's installed), but I cannot find a way to track this.

Since the link mechanism to open the app is entirely on the client-side, there is not a way to distinguish between regular opens of the app and opens that were triggered by a Universal Link.

There are some SDKs that can track this, [Branch.io](https://www.branch.io/) is often suggested. But the documentation doesn't describe exactly how they achieve this tracking.

I have considered changing the schema so that a parameter is passed through to the app. E.g., ?=ULtag and then recording that parameter in GA, but I don't know if this will cause issues with the set up.

How have others overcome the analytics problem with Universal Links?
Thank you.